# Grouping factors or integers into equivalence classes in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame representing equivalences between members from two sets:

```
 print(x)
    G  S
 1 g1 s2
 2 g1 s1
 3 g2 s3
 4 g3 s3
 5 g4 s3
```

Does someone know of a function or a useful data structure for grouping the objects into equivalence classes? In the example above, the result should be two equivalence classes

```
{g1, s1, s2}, {g2, g3, g4, s3}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option is to use `igraph` to extract vertices from clusters:

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_data_frame(x)
m <- clusters(g)$membership
tapply(names(m), m, sort)
```

output:

```
$`1`
[1] "g1" "s1" "s2"

$`2`
[1] "g2" "g3" "g4" "s3"
```

data:

```
x <- read.table(text="G S
g1 s2
g1 s1
g2 s3
g3 s3
g4 s3", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Ah yes, simply let *igraph* partition the graph into connected components. According the igraph documentation, this is done by means of a breadth-first search, so this should be much faster than the solution with *outer*.

Answer (score 2):

You can test for equality using `outer` and combine them with `|` or. From this matrix get the `unique` lines and then use `apply` to return a list of the groups.

```
tt <- outer(x$G, x$G, "==") | outer(x$S, x$S, "==")
tt <- unique(tt)
apply(tt, 1, function(i) unique(unlist(x[i,])))
#[[1]]
#[1] "g1" "s2" "s1"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "g2" "g3" "g4" "s3"
```

Another option which is looping over the vector instead of expanding it as `outer` is doing:

```
y <- unique(x)
t1 <- tt1 <- y[1,1]
t2 <- tt2 <- y[1,2]
y  <- y[-1,]
n <- 1
res  <- list(0)
repeat {
  i <- y[,1] %in% tt1 | y[,2] %in% tt2
  tt  <- y[i,]
  y <- y[!i,]
  tt1  <- unique(tt[!tt[,1] %in% tt1,1])
  tt2  <- unique(tt[!tt[,2] %in% tt2,2])
  if(length(tt1) + length(tt2) > 0) {
    t1  <- c(t1, tt1)
    t2  <- c(t2, tt2)
  } else {
    res[[n]]  <- unique(c(t1, t2))
    if(nrow(y) == 0) break;
    n  <- n + 1
    t1 <- tt1 <- y[1,1]
    t2 <- tt2 <- y[1,2]
    y  <- y[-1,]
  }
}
res
#[[1]]
#[1] "g1" "s2" "s1"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "g2" "g3" "g4" "s3"
```

Data:

```
x <- structure(list(G = c("g1", "g1", "g2", "g3", "g4"), S = c("s2", 
"s1", "s3", "s3", "s3")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Wow, this is clever! Unfortunately it is only applicable to moderately sized data frames because it is an $O(n^2)$ routine.

Comment: @cdalitz Yes the `outer` can become a problem for longer data.

Comment: I have added a runtime comparison of the three suggested solutions. It turns out that this solution based on *outer* is indeed slow for large *n*.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the following code for grouping

```
# function to categorize incoming `v` within existing `lst`
grp <- function(lst, v) {
  if (length(lst) == 0) return(c(lst,list(v)))
  idx <- which(unlist(Map(function(x) any(!is.na(match(v,x))), lst)))
  if (length(idx) == 0) {
    lst <- c(lst,list(v))
  } else {
    lst[idx] <- list(union(unlist(lst[idx]),v))
  }
  return(unique(lst))
}


# generate grouping results
df <- unique(df)
res <- Reduce(function(lst,x) grp(lst,x), 
              c(list(NULL),unname(Map(function(x) as.character(unlist(x)),split(df,seq(nrow(df)))))),
              accumulate = F)
```

**Application Examples**

1. given input data `df <- data.frame(G = c("g1","g1","g2","g3","g4"), S = c("s2","s1","s3","s3","s3"))`
   then

```
> df
   G  S
1 g1 s2
2 g1 s1
3 g2 s3
4 g3 s3
5 g4 s3

> res
[[1]]
[1] "g1" "s2" "s1"

[[2]]
[1] "g2" "s3" "g3" "g4"
```

2. given input data `df <- data.frame(G = sprintf("g%i", c(2,3,4,2,2)), S = sprintf("s%i", c(3,3,2,4,3)))`
   then

```
> df
   G  S
1 g2 s3
2 g3 s3
3 g4 s2
4 g2 s4

> res
[[1]]
[1] "g2" "s3" "g3" "s4"

[[2]]
[1] "g4" "s2"
```

**UPDATE**: above solution become rather slow when dealing with huge dataset. An improved solution is given as below:

```
  G2S <- function(df,g) {
    df[df$G %in% g,]$S
  }
  S2G <- function(df,s) {
    df[df$S %in%s,]$G
  }
  grpFun <- function(df, g) {
    repeat {
      gt <- S2G(df, (s<-G2S(df, g)))
      if (length(gt) == length(g)) return(list(G = gt, S = s))
      g <- gt
    }
  }
  res <- c()
  Gpool <- x$G
  repeat {
    if (length(Gpool)==0) break
    grp <- grpFun(x,Gpool[1])
    Gpool <- setdiff(Gpool,grp$G)
    res <- c(res, list(union(unique(grp$G),unique(grp$S))))
  }
```

Comment: Apart from the problem that this code yields the error "'names' attribute [4] must be the same length as the vector [2]", I must admit that I do not understand it. Should sapply not return as many components as the given vector (names(df) in this case) and thus cannot return more than two groups? Moreover, I wonder what the runtime complexity might be.

Comment: Hi @cdalitz, could you show your test data that errors occurs? I am wondering if there is something due to the data frame you are using not compatible with this solution

Comment: @cdalitz The idea of this solution is to categorize `df` by entries in all columns, and pick out the category with multiple rows, i.e., n-to-1 mapping, and sort out all those groups

Comment: @ThomasCoding The error occurs with exactly the two lines of code posted in your answer. I am using R 3.4.3.

Comment: @cdalitz well....I am using R 3.6.1, maybe that makes difference

Comment: @cdalitz Besides, I am not sure about the computational complexity, but you can compare this with other solution when running with larger dataset, since it's not easy to analysis of running time for `sapply()` with other functions inside

Comment: Concerning complexity: I do not think that *sapply* is a bottleneck, because it is only a loop over two values in this case (names(df) == c("G", "S")). *unique* is *O(m log m)*, where *m* is the number of elements in *unlist(z[unlist(...)])*, which might be *m=O(n^2)* (?).

Comment: @cdalitz What does your `n` refer to here for `m=O(n^2)`? For two groups `"g1, s2, s1", "g2, g3, g4, s3" `,  I would same `m=4` and `6`, respectively.

Comment: I was trying to estimate the runtime complexity as a function of *n=nrow(df)*. Alternatively, you could estimate it as a function of *k.G=length(levels(df$G))* and *k.S=length(levels(df$G))*. It is *n=O(k.G · k.S)*.

Comment: @cdalitz I added another version which is less computationally complex, e.g., probably linear complexity w.r.t. number of rows for each group. You can check it.

Comment: Thanks for the new version, which now runs even on R 3.4.3. Concerning runtime complexity, I must do some tests.

Comment: @cdalitz, That's great it can work on R 3.4.3. Good luck with your test!

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot measure the runtime of this method because it fails for one-to-one mappings, e.g. `x <- data.frame(G = c("g1","g2","g3"), S = c("s1","s2","s3"))`.

Comment: @cdalitz, well...you are right, I did not take one-to-one mapping into account. Please see my updated solution which hopefully can take care of both 1-to-1 and n-to-1 mappings.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code that handles this case. I have made a runtime comparison of all solutions from the three different answers (see my own answer to this question).

Comment: @cdalitz, Fantastic! Thanks you very much for the comparison. I can see that it is more efficient to use some developed package to implement your goal! `igrapha` package seems to be that silver bullet to the runtime issue:)

Comment: "it is more efficient to use some developed package": In general, I prefer a soultion that is only based on builtin functions, because this avoids dependencies and portability issues (installing heavy libraries on old versions of R can be tedious or even impossible). In this particular case, a solution based on *igraph* is welcome, however, because I am using *igraph* anyway.

Comment: @cdalitz Agree! I am also a super fan of using built-in functions :)

Comment: As observed by @GKi (see his answer below), this algorithm yields wrong results (three groups with duplicate entries) for the following input: `x <- data.frame(G = sprintf("g%i", c(2,3,4,2,2)), S = sprintf("s%i", c(3,3,2,4,3)))`. Note that removing the duplicate entry does not help.

Comment: @cdalitz, thanks for pointing out the bug in my program, the bug comes from my improper assumption that your groups may be all exclusive....I will try to solve it, hopefully

Comment: This whole thread has become a total mess with edited answers and other answers pointing out errors in meanwhile edited answers etc. Nevertheless, for an unprepared reader it would be helpful if the proposed solutions would be correct. Thus: it would be welcome, if you can find time to correct this.

Comment: Hi @cdalitz, I corrected my solution by writing a function `grp` for grouping. For the efficiency, I have tried to optimized it but not sure how it works with your dataset.

Comment: Thanks for the new solution. I still run into problems (index out of range) with `G=c(g5,g6,g6,g1,g5,g4), S=c(s2,s5,s6,s4,s4,s5)`. Another error (too many elements) occurs with `G=c(s2,s5,s6,s4,s4,s5), S=c(s2,s5,s2,s6,s2,s3)`. OTOH, as there is a viable solution with *igraph*, it might not be worth the trouble fixing this.

Comment: @cdalitz Sorry that I had a tiny flaw in the last solution. Now it is fixed! You can move on with `igraph`! I am just very interested in implementing it equivalently in `base R`, so I am trying over and over again to make it correct :)

Answer (score 1):

To compare the runtime of the three answers by [@GKi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58839272/11304107), [@chinsoon12](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58847991/11304107), and [@ThomasisCoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58840207/11304107), I have created random sets of different size *n* and measured the runtime (as "elapsed" from *proc.time*).

From the results, I conclude that methods relying on *igraph*'s connected component decomposition is the fastest:

```
    n chinsoon12 ThomasisCoding   GKi
  500      0.002          0.054 0.030
 2500      0.010          0.203 0.416
 5000      0.020          0.379 1.456
 7500      0.033          0.670 3.351
10000      0.044          0.832 5.837
```

[image: run time of different algorithms]

**Edit (2019-11-19):** Upon request of [@GKI](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10488504/gki), here is the code I used for comparing the runtime of the three algorithms. Beware that all functions work on the *global* variable *x*, because R only supports call-by-value, which would add unwanted overhead in this runtime estimation:

```
library(igraph)

# solution by chinsson12: CC decomposition from igraph
method.A <- function() {
    g <- graph_from_data_frame(x)
    m <- clusters(g)$membership
    res <- tapply(names(m), m, sort)
    return(res)
}

# solution by ThomasisCoding
method.B <- function() {
  # find 1-to-1 mapping
  r <- Reduce(intersect,lapply(names(x), function(v) split(x,x[v])))
  r1map <- unlist(Map(toString,Map(unlist,r)))
  # removel one-to-one mapping and find N-to-1 mapping
  if (length(r1map) >0) {
    xx <- x[-as.numeric(rownames(Reduce(rbind,r))),]
  } else {
    xx <- x
  }
  rNmap <- c()
  if (nrow(xx)> 0) {
    rNmap <- sapply(names(xx),
                    function(v) {
                      z <- split(xx,xx[v])
                      u <- z[unlist(Map(nrow,z))>1]
                      ifelse(length(u)==0, NA, toString(c(names(u),as.vector(u[[1]][,setdiff(names(xx),v)]))))
                    },USE.NAMES = F)
    rNmap <- rNmap[!is.na(rNmap)]
  }
  # combine both 1-to-1 and n-to-1 mappings
  res <- c(r1map,rNmap)
  return(res)
}

# solution by GKi: with outer product
method.C <- function() {
    tt <- outer(x$G, x$G, "==") | outer(x$S, x$S, "==")
    tt <- unique(tt)
    res <- apply(tt, 1, function(i) unique(unlist(x[i,])))
    return(res)
}

# runtime results
rt <- data.frame()
for (n in seq(500,10000, by=500)) {
    # this won't work because of ambigous node ids (see [answer by GKi][6]):
    #x <- data.frame(G = sample(1:n,n,replace=TRUE), S = sample(1:n,n,replace=TRUE))
    # therefore, make the node ids unique:
    x <- data.frame(G = sprintf("g%i", sample(1:n,n,replace=TRUE)), S = sprintf("s%i", sample(1:n,n,replace=TRUE)))

    t1 <- proc.time()
    method.A()
    tA <- proc.time() - t1
    t1 <- proc.time()
    method.B()
    tB <- proc.time() - t1
    t1 <- proc.time()
    method.C()
    tC <- proc.time() - t1

  rt <- rbind(rt, data.frame(n=n, t.A=tA[["elapsed"]], t.B=tB[["elapsed"]], t.C=tC[["elapsed"]]))
}

print(rt)

plot(rt$n, rt$t.C, xlab="n", ylab="run time [s]", ylim=c(min(rt$t.A),max(rt$t.C)), type='l')
lines(rt$n, rt$t.B, col="red")
lines(rt$n, rt$t.A, col="blue")
legend("topleft", c("GKi", "ThomasisCoding", "chinsoon12"), lt=c(1,1,1), col=c("black", "red", "blue"))
```

Comment: Can you share the code, to enable testing other methods?

Comment: Thanks! Have you realized, that the methods are returning different results?

Answer (score 1):

Comparison on results of the methods:

```
method.A()
#$`1`
#[1] "1" "2" "3" "4"

method.A2()
#$`1`
#[1] "3" "1" "4" "2"
#
#$`2`
#[1] "2" "3"

method.B()
#[[1]]
#[1] 3 1 4 2
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 2 3

method.C()
#[[1]]
#[[1]]$All
#[1] 3 1 4 2
#
#[[1]]$G
#[1] 3 1
#
#[[1]]$S
#[1] 4 2 1
#
#
#[[2]]
#[[2]]$All
#[1] 2 3
#
#[[2]]$G
#[1] 2
#
#[[2]]$S
#[1] 3
```

Methods:

```
library(igraph)
method.A <- function() {
    g <- graph_from_data_frame(x)
    m <- clusters(g)$membership
    res <- tapply(names(m), m, sort)
    return(res)
}

method.A2 <- function() {
    g <- graph_from_data_frame(t(apply(x, 1, function(x) paste0(names(x), x))))
    m <- clusters(g)$membership
    res <- tapply(substring(names(m),2), m, unique)
    return(res)
}

method.B <- function() {
  G2S <- function(df,g) {
    df[df$G %in% g,]$S
  }
  S2G <- function(df,s) {
    df[df$S %in%s,]$G
  }
  grpFun <- function(df, g) {
    repeat {
      gt <- S2G(df, (s<-G2S(df, g)))
      if (length(gt) == length(g)) return(list(G = gt, S = s))
      g <- gt
    }
  }
  res <- c()
  Gpool <- x$G
  repeat {
    if (length(Gpool)==0) break
    grp <- grpFun(x,Gpool[1])
    Gpool <- setdiff(Gpool,grp$G)
    res <- c(res, list(union(unique(grp$G),unique(grp$S))))
  }
  return(res)
}

method.C <- function() {
  y <- unique(x)
  t1 <- tt1 <- y[1,1]
  t2 <- tt2 <- y[1,2]
  y  <- y[-1,]
  n <- 1
  res  <- list(0)
  repeat {
    i <- y[,1] %in% tt1 | y[,2] %in% tt2
    tt  <- y[i,]
    y <- y[!i,]
    tt1  <- unique(tt[!tt[,1] %in% tt1,1])
    tt2  <- unique(tt[!tt[,2] %in% tt2,2])
    if(length(tt1) + length(tt2) > 0) {
      t1  <- c(t1, tt1)
      t2  <- c(t2, tt2)
    } else {
      res[[n]]  <- list(All=unique(c(t1, t2)), G=unique(t1), S=unique(t2))
      if(nrow(y) == 0) break;
      n  <- n + 1
      t1 <- tt1 <- y[1,1]
      t2 <- tt2 <- y[1,2]
      y  <- y[-1,]
    }
  }
  res
}
```

Data:

```
x <- data.frame(G = c(3,1,1,2,3), S=c(4,1,2,3,2))
x
#  G S
#1 3 4
#2 1 1
#3 1 2
#4 2 3
#5 3 2
```

Comment: Thanks for testing this! It turns out that the only correct result is from the *igraph* CC decomposition. This is not visible in this example, because `apply(names() ...` fails when the names between the two classes overlap, but the result in *m* is correct (this could be resoved by making the names unique, as with `G=sprintf("g%i", sample(...)), S=sprintf("s%i", sample(...)))`.

Comment: @cdalitz I think also `mehtod.C` come to the correct result. And this already for `integer` and not only for `character`. Also the result in `m` seems not to be correct for `integer` in `method.A`.

Comment: Concerning *method.C*, I had implemented your first, shorter version. The longer version indeed returns the correct result in the attribute `$All`. Concerning *method.A*, when integers are used and there is overlap between the two set of integers, these overlapping integers are (correctly, but unintendedly) interpreted by *igraph* as the same nodes. *methodB()* is indeed incorrect, however, but I cannot fix it because I do not understand this solution :-(

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: performance comparison based on latest updates by [@GKi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58839272/11304107), [@chinsoon12](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58847991/11304107), and [@ThomasisCoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58840207/11304107)

- code for comparison

```
library(igraph)
method.A <- function() {
  g <- graph_from_data_frame(x)
  m <- clusters(g)$membership
  res <- tapply(names(m), m, sort)
  return(res)
}

method.B <- function() {
  G2S <- function(df,g) {
    df[df$G %in% g,]$S
  }
  S2G <- function(df,s) {
    df[df$S %in%s,]$G
  }
  grpFun <- function(df, g) {
    repeat {
      gt <- S2G(df, (s<-G2S(df, g)))
      if (length(gt) == length(g)) return(list(G = gt, S = s))
      g <- gt
    }
  }
  res <- c()
  Gpool <- x$G
  repeat {
    if (length(Gpool)==0) break
    grp <- grpFun(x,Gpool[1])
    Gpool <- setdiff(Gpool,grp$G)
    res <- c(res, list(union(unique(grp$G),unique(grp$S))))
  }
  return(res)
}

method.C <- function() {
  y <- unique(x)
  t1 <- tt1 <- y[1,1]
  t2 <- tt2 <- y[1,2]
  y  <- y[-1,]
  n <- 1
  res  <- list(0)
  repeat {
    i <- y[,1] %in% tt1 | y[,2] %in% tt2
    tt  <- y[i,]
    y <- y[!i,]
    tt1  <- unique(tt[!tt[,1] %in% tt1,1])
    tt2  <- unique(tt[!tt[,2] %in% tt2,2])
    if(length(tt1) + length(tt2) > 0) {
      t1  <- c(t1, tt1)
      t2  <- c(t2, tt2)
    } else {
      res[[n]]  <- list(All=unique(c(t1, t2)), G=unique(t1), S=unique(t2))
      if(nrow(y) == 0) break;
      n  <- n + 1
      t1 <- tt1 <- y[1,1]
      t2 <- tt2 <- y[1,2]
      y  <- y[-1,]
    }
  }
  res
}

# runtime results
rt <- data.frame()
for (n in seq(500,10000, by=500)) {
  # this won't work because of ambigous node ids (see [answer by GKi][6]):
  #x <- data.frame(G = sample(1:n,n,replace=TRUE), S = sample(1:n,n,replace=TRUE))
  # therefore, make the node ids unique:
  x <- data.frame(G = sprintf("g%i", sample(1:n,n,replace=TRUE)), S = sprintf("s%i", sample(1:n,n,replace=TRUE)))

  t1 <- proc.time()
  method.A()
  tA <- proc.time() - t1
  t1 <- proc.time()
  method.B()
  tB <- proc.time() - t1
  t1 <- proc.time()
  method.C()
  tC <- proc.time() - t1

  rt <- rbind(rt, data.frame(n=n, t.A=tA[["elapsed"]], t.B=tB[["elapsed"]], t.C=tC[["elapsed"]]))
}

print(rt)

plot(rt$n, rt$t.C, xlab="n", ylab="run time [s]", ylim=c(min(rt$t.A),max(rt$t.C)), type='l')
lines(rt$n, rt$t.B, col="red")
lines(rt$n, rt$t.A, col="blue")
legend("topleft", c("GKi", "ThomasisCoding", "chinsoon12"), lt=c(1,1,1), col=c("black", "red", "blue"))
```

- runtime of three methods:

```
       n  t.A   t.B   t.C
1    500 0.00  0.16  0.26
2   1000 0.02  0.31  0.53
3   1500 0.02  0.51  1.11
4   2000 0.03  0.90  1.47
5   2500 0.03  1.35  2.17
6   3000 0.04  2.08  3.14
7   3500 0.04  2.66  3.97
8   4000 0.07  3.38  4.92
9   4500 0.07  4.38  6.35
10  5000 0.06  5.41  7.58
11  5500 0.08  6.79  9.55
12  6000 0.08  7.81 10.91
13  6500 0.10  9.03 12.06
14  7000 0.09 10.06 14.20
15  7500 0.11 11.76 15.65
16  8000 0.13 13.41 17.84
17  8500 0.11 14.87 20.67
18  9000 0.13 16.88 23.52
19  9500 0.14 18.38 25.57
20 10000 0.14 22.81 30.05
```

- visualization of runtime
  [image]

**Additional (Thanks to comment by [@GKi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58839272/11304107))**: When keeping the dataset `integers`, the grouping process `non-igraph` methods are largely reduced:

```
       n  t.A  t.B  t.C
1    500 0.00 0.09 0.13
2   1000 0.01 0.15 0.23
3   1500 0.01 0.22 0.38
4   2000 0.03 0.31 0.50
5   2500 0.05 0.45 0.76
6   3000 0.07 0.51 0.77
7   3500 0.06 0.67 0.97
8   4000 0.07 0.85 1.20
9   4500 0.07 0.90 1.39
10  5000 0.09 1.23 1.55
11  5500 0.09 1.30 1.78
12  6000 0.09 1.51 1.94
13  6500 0.11 1.77 2.20
14  7000 0.13 2.18 2.55
15  7500 0.12 2.37 2.79
16  8000 0.13 2.56 2.96
17  8500 0.14 2.76 3.39
18  9000 0.15 3.03 3.54
19  9500 0.15 3.54 4.23
20 10000 0.16 3.76 4.32
```

[image]

Comment: @cdalitz an updated comparison was added, now you can see the performance of the latest methods by different authors. Just for fun to make this!

Comment: Thanks for taking the trouble of testing this! Apparently the first two methods have quadratic runtime complexity. Did you also verify whether the results are the same?

Comment: @cdalitz Welcome! Yes, `igraph` dominates the performance for sure. I tested my code for several samples, which gives the same result as `method.A()`, but not sure if it can survive from pressure test

Comment: When keeping the dataset on `integers` you can speed up the results from the non-igraph answers by ~10. As the question was *Grouping factors or integers* and non-igraph can work with `integers` I think it's OK to show the time when working with `integers`.

Comment: @GKi, thanks a lot for the advice. The runtime for dataset on `integers` is added.