# Cluster observations based on multiple variables

Tags: r, aggregate, cluster-computing

I am looking for an r function to create clusters in my dataset based on two variables (hope "cluster" is the right name for what I want to do) . Every two observations with the same value for variable_1 OR variable_2, should be in the same cluster. In the brief exemple that follows, I aggregating dataframe df based on variable_1 and variable_2.

```
df <- data.frame(variable_1=c("a","a","b","b","c","c","d","d","e","e"),variable_2=c("g1","g2","g1","g3","g2","g4","g4","g6","g7","g8"),value=rnorm(10))

df$clusters <- some_function_to_create_clusters(df[,c("variable_1","variable_2")])
```

The result should look like:

```
df$clusters <- c("clu1","clu1","clu1","clu1","clu1","clu1","clu1","clu1","clu2","clu2")
df
```

Notice that the first cluster contains everyone with variable_1 equals "a", "b", "c", or "d": "a" and "b" are merged together because they share "g1" (lines 1 and 3); "a" and "c" are merged because they share "g2" (lines 2 and 5); and "c" and "d" are merged because they share "g4" (lines 6 and 7). 
Finally, in the last cluster there are only observations with variable_1=="e", because they don't share variable_2 with anyone.

Just to clarify what I intend to do, I will explain my problem set a little better. I’m pairing counties with nearby Touristic Attractions. Different counties are surround by different Touristic Attraction (TA), and there are many TA around the same county. But this "touristic-clusters" of counties and TAs are sparsely spread in the country. Notice that some far away counties might be inside the same cluster due to a “chain” effect of county-Touristic Attraction connections. So I want to find those “clusters” based on the id of the county and of the Touristic Attraction.

This seems simple, but I can't figure it out how to implement.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Maybe this is something related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58838981/grouping-factors-or-integers-into-equivalence-classes-in-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## igraph solution

*Disclaimer: I am completely new to igraph, so there's probably a better solution to this problem. However this seems to work.*

With the `igraph` package we can cluster the data using the `graph_from_data_frame()` function, and then extract the clusters with `components`. You get the added advantage of being able to visualise the clusters.

```
library(igraph)

graph <- graph_from_data_frame(df[, 1:2], directed = FALSE)

cmp <- components(graph)$membership

df$cluster <- cmp[df$variable_1]

plot(graph)
```

[image: igraph cluster plot]

## Wrapping it up into a function

If you wanted to wrap it up as a function, something like this works:

```
find_clusters <- function(x, y) {
  edges <- data.frame(from = x, to = y)
  graph <- igraph::graph_from_data_frame(edges, directed = FALSE)
  cmp <- igraph::components(graph)$membership
  return(cmp[x])
}
```

Using the additional example you posted as a comment above, we thus have the following workflow:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
    variable_1 = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "d", "d", "e", "e", "f", "f"),
    variable_2 = c( "g1", "g2", "g1", "g3", "g2", "g4", "g4", "g6", "g7", "g8", "g9", "g12"),
    value = rnorm(12)
  )

df %>% 
  mutate(cluster = find_clusters(variable_1, variable_2))

#    variable_1 variable_2       value  cluster
# 1           a         g1 -0.03410073        1
# 2           a         g2  0.51261548        1
# 3           b         g1  0.06470451        1
# 4           b         g3 -1.97228101        1
# 5           c         g2 -0.39751063        1
# 6           c         g4  0.17761619        1
# 7           d         g4 -0.13771207        1
# 8           d         g6 -0.72183017        1
# 9           e         g7  0.09012701        2
# 10          e         g8  0.45763593        2
# 11          f         g9 -0.83172613        3
# 12          f        g12  2.83480352        3
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I wrote a function to achieve what I need. It is ugly but it is working. If someone has a better/more efficient solution I would really appreciate it.

```
find_clusters <- function(original_df){

  find_clus <- original_df
  cluster_number <- 1
  find_clus$cluster <- "cl"
  i=1
  for(i in 1:nrow(find_clus)){
    if(nchar(find_clus$cluster[i])>2) next
    aux <- lapply(original_df,function(x){ which(x==x[i])})%>% reshape2::melt()
    idx <- aux$value %>%unique() %>%sort()
    j = 1
    while(j <= length(idx)){
      aux <- lapply(original_df,function(x){ which(x==x[idx[j]])})%>% reshape2::melt()
      idx <- c( idx, aux$value) %>%unique() %>% sort()
      j <- j+1
    }


    find_clus$cluster[idx] <- paste0("cl",sprintf("%04d",  cluster_number))
    cluster_number<- cluster_number +1
  }  
  return(find_clus$cluster)
}
```

So, to find the clusters one should write:

```
find_clusters(df[,c(1,2)])
```