# Sequentially update a vector in R

Tags: r, vector

Hello I have a vector such as

```
x<-c(**131144**,**1311605**,1311766,1312289,1312804) in R
```

And then another data frame like:

```
v1     , v2
**131144,1283758**
**1283758,19527672**
**1311605,19950311**
198151,37268685
**19950311,35307140**
11281862,11292508
35261079,26296073
625349,37306860
84255273,84259752
```

I would like to end up with a final vector like this one

```
x<-c(**19527672**,**19950311**,1311766,1312289,1312804)
```

Is like to iteratively searching for a value and when a match is found updating it and then keep searching for the updated value until no match found.

Thks in advance.

Comment: Why is the second value in your expected outcome not `35307140`?

Answer (score 0):

Alittle tweak to the [solution found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63305399/finding-the-hierarchy-relationships-between-number-pairs-in-r/63305628#63305628) and we have the following:

```
relation <- function(vec, dat){
  .relation <- function(x){
    k = unique(c(dat[dat[, 1] %in% x, 2], x, dat[dat[, 2] %in% x, 1]))
    if(setequal(x,k)) tail(k, 2)[1] else Recall(k)
  }
  y <- unique(vec)
  sapply(y, .relation)[match(vec, y)]
}

relation(x, df)
[1] 19527672 35307140  1311766  1312289  1312804
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `igraph`

```
g <- graph_from_data_frame(df)
v <- membership(components(g))
tb <- by(names(v), v, function(x) x[degree(g, x, mode = "out") == 0])
m <- unname(v[as.character(x)])
ifelse(is.na(m), x, as.numeric(tb[m]))
```

gives

```
[1] 19527672 35307140  1311766  1312289  1312804
```

where `plot(g)` shows

[image]